# Test android application as on real device

Tags: android

I test my android application on emulator now i want to test my application on device, but i do not have android device.

So is there any tool on web that can test my android app as its on real device ?

Any help is highly appreciated .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Emulator is also a device( not physical but a virtual one)

Comment: You are right, but in my application i shared some data with social site with inbuilt android intent . so there are no such social intent in emulator like facebook,twitter,peep etc.That's why i want to test on real device

Comment: Then I think you have to download these apps for emulator. Wll I think, but not sure.

Comment: For that i need android market on emulator.

Comment: Whoever voted to close this or downoted it - this is a perfectly valid and good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the best web tool to test your android application on web as real device.

[www.perfectomobile.com](http://www.perfectomobile.com)

**It gives 1 hour free trial to test your app.**

Answer (score 5):

You can use the samsung remote test lab

http://developer.samsung.com/remoteTestLab.do

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend [testobject](http://www.testobject.com).
They have an  pool of real devices as well as emulators that you can use to stress test your app, generate quality report, automate your testing and setup your custom tests, etc. etc.
It´s a pretty reliable Cloud service. And the pricing is pretty fair, so it´s definitely worth give it a try.